# React Navigation Slide Animation goBack Button error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I get this error:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:623)
    in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at src/index.native.tsx:147)
    in Screen (at Screens.tsx:74)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:616)
```

This is my navigator:

```js
const DefaultStackNavigation = () => {
  return(
    <NavigationContainer fallback={<View style={{backgroundColor: "#0C0C0C", height: "100%", width: "100%", flex: 1}} />}>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false, gestureEnabled: true, gestureDirection: "horizontal", cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS, cardStyle: {backgroundColor: "transparent", flex: 1, height: "100%", width: "100%"}}} independent={false}>
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeTabs" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ChatScreen" component={ChatScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Because I have `gestureEnabled`= `true` I can swipe the screen to the right to go back. But now there is a problem:

I want the user to choose wether he/she want's to swipe to go back or if he/she want's to click on the go back button. If I swipe the screen to the right I don't get an error and I can use the app. But if I click on my `navigation.goBack()` button in my ChatScreen I get the error (beginning of this post). If I than enable the header and click on the goBack button I don't get this error too.
How can I prevent React Native to behave this way?

### Edit

This is my goBack button:

```js
<View style={styles.backArrowContainer}>
  <TouchableOpacity style={{height: 60, width: 60, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
    <BackArrow />
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: Can you add you chatscreen code and header aswell

Comment: Yeah, for sure :)

Comment: Did you find out a solution for this?

Comment: Yes and no:
I couldn't solve *this* error, but I found out a way to make the app even faster and to bypass the "bug": Instead of a normal Stack-Navigator I now use the Native-Stack-Navigator. There I have a similar slide animation for Android and the IOS-native animation for IOS.